# How to associate entities during seed with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Module
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public string FontAwesomeClass { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ModulosPorUsuario
{
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<Module> Modules{ get; set; }
}
```

And I need to seed like this:

```
#region Seed Modules
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-ambulance" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 2, ModuleName = "Recursos Humanos", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-heartbeat" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Inventario", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-anchor" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Produccion", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-binoculars" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Ventas", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-coffee" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Compras", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-calendar-o" });
    context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Cotizaciones", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-building" });
    #endregion
```

However my question is how can I associate a list of modules that were previously seeded??

```
    #region Seed ModulosPor Usuario
    context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
    {
        Email = "companyadmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
        Modules = ???
    });

    #endregion
```

**Update 1:**

When I check the tables created for me this doesnt look right.  A module is an entity by its own, and ModulesPeruser should be a relationship between email and many different modules.
However on the Module table it created a foreign key to ModulesPerUser.

What is wrong with my design?
http://screencast.com/t/Z0u2950zm

Comment: Now you're asking two questions. Stick to the first one and ask another one for the updated part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var module1 = new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-ambulance" };
context.Modulos.Add(module);
context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
    Email = "companyadmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    Modules = new List<Module>(){module1, module2 etc...};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list of modules and after call `dbContext.SaveChanges()`assign that collection to the modulosPorUsuario object and save changes again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var modules = new List<Module>()
{
    new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-ambulance" },
    new Module() { Id = 2, ModuleName = "Recursos Humanos", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-heartbeat" },
    new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Inventario", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-anchor" },
    new Module() { Id = 4, ModuleName = "Produccion", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-binoculars" },
    new Module() { Id = 6, ModuleName = "Ventas", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-coffee" },
    new Module() { Id = 7, ModuleName = "Compras", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-calendar-o" },
    new Module() { Id = 8, ModuleName = "Cotizaciones", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-building" }
};

context.ModulosPorUsuario.Add(new ModulosPorUsuario()
{
    Email = "companyadmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    Modules = modules
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to be aware of:

1. Seeding runs every time you update the database. As a result, you should use `AddOrUpdate`, rather than `Add`, to keep from adding the same items multiple times.
2. When using `AddOrUpdate`, only simple data types are updated (string, int, etc.). Properties referencing class instances or list properties will *not* be updated.

To get around the second point, you should update id properties rather than reference properties. For example, given the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

You would need to structure your seed like:

```
var bar1 = new Bar { Name = "Bar 1" };
var bar2 = new Bar { Name = "Bar 2" };
var bar3 = new Bar { Name = "Bar 3" };

context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
    r => r.Name,
    bar1,
    bar2,
    bar3
 );

 context.SaveChanges();

 context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
     r => r.Name,
     new Foo
     {
         Name = "Foo",
         BarId = bar1.Id
     }
  );
```

That way, if you want to change the `Bar` instance, the `Foo` is associated with, you can. If you were to use `Bar = bar1` instead, it would be ignored on update.

The same goes for your list properties. In a one-to-many situation, you should set the relationship on the principal side as in the sample code above, rather than setting the list property directly, `Bar.Foos` in this example.

In a many-to-many, you simply won't be able to update the relationship, since both sides have a collection and you don't have any access to the join table. You can initially seed the relationships, but you won't be able to update them in future seeds.